# How to generate unique string from number which lies in range of quantity of characters ' permutations in this string?

Tags: string, algorithm, math, permutation

Suppose I could have a string with length 8 bytes, each byte is a character from one of the next ranges: 0-9,a-z,A-Z, totally 62 variants. Total number of permutations of this string is 62 to the power of 8 = 218340105584896.
I need to write a function which will accept number in range
0-218340105584896 and return unique string. Under the unique I mean that function cannot return the same string for two different numbers in this range. Any code examples and hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately this is [off topics on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). What you want to do is however called *lexicographical order unranking*, and you may find [this paper](https://ldc.usb.ve/~bonet/reports/AAAI08-ws10-ranking.pdf) useful.

Comment: @LSerni Thank you, I will study this paper and try to provide working code example for my question by my own, maybe it will be useful for someone.

Comment: @LSerni: that paper is about *permutations*; although OP uses the word permutations, the question is about [Cartesian powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_power) of a set, which is quite a different thing. Moreover, [ask] does specifically allow questions about "a software algorithm", so it is not completely clear that the question is off-topic. It has, however, been answered many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could treat the number as a base 62 number, and fill in the string "digits" (base-62 bits) accordingly.

Let's see how we do this with the decimal number 1234 in different bases. note that division below is always integer division (fractional parts are chopped off).

Base 10 (decimal): 0-9

```
1234 / 10^3 = 1, 1234 mod 10^3 = 234
234 / 10^2 = 2, 234 mod 10^2 = 34
34 / 10^1 = 3, 34 mod 10^1 = 4
4 / 10^0 = 4, 4 mod 10^0 = 0
Thus we represent this number in base-10 as "1234"
```

Base 16 (hexadecimal): 0-9,a-f (where a=10, b=11, ...)

```
1234 / 16^2 = 4, 1234 mod 16^2 = 210
210 / 16^1 = d, 210 mod 16^1 = 2
2 / 16^0 = 2, 2 mod 16^0 = 0
Thus we represent this number in base-16 as "4d2"
```

This could extend to any base, including base-62: 0-9,a-z,A-Z

```
1234 / 62^1 = j, 1234 mod 62^1 = 56
56 / 62^0 = U, 56 mod 62^0 = 0
Thus we represent this number in base-62 as "jU"
```

I didn't bother doing leading 0's, but you could see that 1234 / 62^2 = 0, and 1234 mod 62^2 = 1234, so in base-62 you can have "000000jU".

---

Note that you could only do this for numbers in the range [0, 218340105584896), so it wouldn't be possible to represent 218340105584896.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, then just yesterday I put a JavaScript code that answers it to another question [Get offset in combinations without generating all possible combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478393/get-offset-in-combinations-without-generating-all-possible-combinations/48479886#48479886) The method you are interested in is `indexToPermutation`. Note that JS has some limitations on number types so it will not work for your range but if you translate it into some other language that supports 64-bit `long` integer type, it should work. Unfortunately you didn't put any language tag so I can't do a translation myself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me and i upvoted it, but yoyoyango provided  explanation here, so I accepted his answer.

Comment: @User590254, obviously you are free to accept any answer that you think deserves it. In my defense I think that the referenced answer contains "Some math behind it" section with similar explanation so I didn't provide it here.